# Make select field selected based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, parameters

```
<%= select("category", "category_id", Category.all.collect { |p| [ p.title, p.id] },{include_blank: "All Category"},{class: "form-control"}  ) %>   

<div class="col-auto"> 
  <%= button_tag( class: "btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-rounded search-button-style") do %>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <span><%= I18n.t 'search' %></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I have a select field. I need to select the data based on params. I will be getting `category_id` in the params  as `params[:category][:category_id]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<%= select("category", "category_id", Category.all.collect { |p| [ p.title, p.id] }, { include_blank: "All Category", selected: params[:category][:category_id] }, { class: "form-control" }) %>
```

The `select` method accepts `selected` in the options to choose one as selected.

This method is useful when generating a `form` for a model where it would autoselect the chosen option. You can also use `select_tag` like this if you wish:

```
<%= select_tag("category_id", options_for_select(Category.all.collect { |p| [ p.title, p.id] }, params[:category][:category_id]), include_blank: "All Category", class: "form-control") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the parameter `selected` you can set the value which should be selected.

```
<%= select("category", "category_id", Category.all.collect { |p| [ p.title, p.id] },{include_blank: "All Category", selected: value},{class: "form-control"} ) %>
```